# fread (buffer=struct, size of struct, count of struct in array, array) possible?

Tags: c, arrays, struct, fread

my function looks like this so far:

```
int orderList (struct artikel_t * order_arr, int arr_size_order)
{
struct artikel_t akt_artikel_order;

int icount_order=0;
struct order_list {
    int lfd_nr;
    int art_nr;
    char bezeichner[MAXCHAR];
    int bestellmenge;
    float preis;
    float gesamtpreis;};


struct order_list bestellung[arr_size_order];

while (fread(&akt_artikel_order, akt_artikel_order, arr_size_order, order_arr) < arr_size_order)
{

    bestellung[icount_order].lfd_nr=icount_order;
    bestellung[icount_order].art_nr=akt_artikel_order[icount_order].art_nr
    strcpy(bestellung(icount_count).bezeichner, "akt_artikel_order.bezeichner");

    bestellung[icount_order].bestellmenge=(akt_artikel_order[icount_order].min)*4);
    bestellung[icount_order].preis=akt_artikel_order[icount_order].preis;
    bestellung[icount_order].gesamtpreis=((akt_artikel_order[icount_order].preis)*(akt_artikel_order[icount_order].min)*4);

    icount_order++;

}
}
```

the function orderList receives the adress of the first element of an array of the type struct artikel_t that was created in another function and delivered to the main before orderList is opened; this array contains arr_size_order elements. The function orderList is then supposed to create a new array of the type struct order_list. The elements of each structure in the array ( lfd_nr, art_nr,...) are then filled with the data from where *orderArray is pointing to.

I will write the rest of the function (to send the array to stdout in useful was, etc. ) later.

My Question: is the fread function properly written and is it legit to use fread  a) read from arrays and b) read structures?

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: It is, but it doesn't do what you think it does because of padding.

Comment: doesnt padding sort my struct out so that they all have the same length independent of the actual content? Hence the term "akt_artikel_order" would be a legitimate size specification?

Comment: `size_t fread(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream);` The last argument of `fread` must be a `FILE*`. If you pass a `struct artikel_t *`, your compiler ought to raise a handful of eyebrows.